# Duplicated rows emerging when using group_by and summarise

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a data table and I get duplicated rows when using the summarise function combined with group_by.

I will give a simplified example of my problem.
First, I am using group_by and mutate to add the sum of 'value' for each id.

```
dt <- data.table(id = rep(1:5, each=10), cpc = rep((0.1*seq(5)), each=2), value = 1:50)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(SumValue = sum(value))


Source: local data table [50 x 4]

   id cpc value SumValue
1   1 0.1     1       55
2   1 0.1     2       55
3   1 0.2     3       55
4   1 0.2     4       55
5   1 0.3     5       55
6   1 0.3     6       55
7   1 0.4     7       55
8   1 0.4     8       55
9   1 0.5     9       55
10  1 0.5    10       55
.. .. ...   ...      ...
```

So far, nothing wrong.
But after that, when I do group_by for each id,cpc combination and use summarise, the output is not as I expected.
The numbers are correct, but there are duplicated rows.

```
dt2 %>%
  group_by(id, cpc) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), SumValue = SumValue)

Source: local data table [50 x 4]
Groups: id

   id cpc count SumValue
1   1 0.1     2       55
2   1 0.1     2       55
3   1 0.2     2       55
4   1 0.2     2       55
5   1 0.3     2       55
6   1 0.3     2       55
7   1 0.4     2       55
8   1 0.4     2       55
9   1 0.5     2       55
10  1 0.5     2       55
.. .. ...   ...      ...
```

Using unique() gives the desired result, but I suppose that this is not necessary.

```
dt2 %>%
  group_by(id, cpc) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), SumValue = SumValue) %>%
  unique()

Source: local data table [25 x 4]
Groups: id

   id cpc count SumValue
1   1 0.1     2       55
2   1 0.2     2       55
3   1 0.3     2       55
4   1 0.4     2       55
5   1 0.5     2       55
6   2 0.1     2      155
7   2 0.2     2      155
8   2 0.3     2      155
9   2 0.4     2      155
10  2 0.5     2      155
.. .. ...   ...      ...
```

I thought that group_by sets group when add=FALSE, so I don't know why the duplicated rows are emerging.

Comment: Try `dt2 %>% group_by(id, cpc) %>% summarise(count=n(), SumValue=SumValue[1L])` .  In the `dt2`, you created `SumValue` using `mutate`, So there must be mutliple rows that have the same `SumValue` for each `id`

Comment: Thanks akrun, your solution seems to work without using unique().
Now I see that the problem is the SumValue=SumValue part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact problem, but when you assign a vector to a summarize variable, you usually need pick one element of the vector. So in this case you need to pick which value of "SumValue" to assign to a the summarised "SumValue". I usually just do this with variable[1], but first(variable) might be better. Does this give you the result you're looking for?

```
dt <- data_frame(id = rep(1:5, each=10), 
                 cpc = rep((0.1*seq(5)), each=10), 
                 value = 1:50)
dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(SumValue = sum(value))
dt2

dt2 %>%
  group_by(id, cpc) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), SumValue = first(SumValue))
```

Comment: I forgot that "SumValue" is a vector and that I should pick one element of it. Thanks for pointing this out Shorpy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using unique in this way. Not exactly sure if this will help.

```
R> df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,3,2), b=c(4,5,6,6,4,3)) 
R> unique(unlist(df)) 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be corrected by adding SumValue to group_by() rather than including it in summarise():

```
  dt2 <- dt %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(SumValueById = sum(value))
```

Returns each row, appending the sum(value) by ID, so now ID and SumValueById are perfectly correlated.  So, to get the desired result you can just add SumValueById to the grouping variables, and tell summarise to keep the grouping variables in the result:

```
  dt2 %>% 
    group_by(id,cpc,SumValueById) %>% 
    summarise(count = n(), .groups="keep")
```

If you also wanted the sum(value) by ID and CPC, you could add that as well:

```
  dt2 %>% 
    group_by(id,cpc,SumValueById) %>% 
    summarise(count = n(), 
              SumValueByIdCPC = sum(value))
```